# Textbox KeyBinding with AcceptsReturn = true

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

Basically I have a textbox which will accept return when a checkbox is unchecked and when it's checked I want the textbox to react on KeyBinding I wrote.

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=EnterCheckbox, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}" >
     <TextBox.InputBindings>
           <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding CmdEnterPressed}"/>
     </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox >
```

Now in any cases, despite of fact that `TextBox.AcceptsReturn` is set to True when I press `[Return]` KeyBinding is firing and I want not to fire it but to go to next line of TB.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement CanExecute for that command like this:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    bool acceptReturns = (bool)parameter;
    return !acceptReturns;
}
```

And in your XAML (as far as CommandParameter is used for both Execute and CanExecute methods):

```
<KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding CmdEnterPressed}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=AcceptsReturn}"/>
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't help. Even when CanExecute returns False it always do the Command mechanism, not AcceptsReturn. Now I'm trying to achieve that with Interactivity dll. Maybe it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem and the suggested solutions did not fix it. Here is how I worked around it.

- Leave the first textbox with keybinding as is and create an almost exact copy minus the keybinding and had AcceptReturn set to true
- Set/Attache the visibility of both (the second inversely) to the Checkbox isChecked property
- Bind the text to the same property

There should be a better fix, but this did it for me